# Do I need Schengen visa? If so, working permit or visitor?

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel, refugees

I'm currently a green card holder through asylum (my nationality was Indonesian). Also I have the travel document (refugee travel document).
Work requires me to travel to Brussels for a team training. To go there, will I need visa? **If so, what kind of visa I should apply?**

Comment: Note that you need to travel on the [Refugee Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/D4en.pdf), not the Re-Entry Permit (which, while you _can_ travel on it, will require visas).

Comment: Yes, i stated above that i hold travel document. Furthermore,if i required visa, then what type of schengen visa? Will i need working permit or i can just use visitor visa.

Comment: The Refugee Travel Document and Re-Entry Permit are two completely different documents. You should be traveling on the Refugee Travel Document; you only need the Re-Entry Permit if you will be outside the US for more than a year or want to reside in another country. And, as the linked question explains, you are visa-exempt for short stays if you travel to Belgium on the Refugee Travel Document.

Comment: I just confirmed again, mine is actually refugee travel document, not re-entry permit.

Comment: You can just book your flight and go, _however_ you need to make sure that Belgium is the first country where you enter the Schengen area. If you don't get a direct flight to Brussels from the US, you should arrange to transit outside Schengen (e.g. the UK, where you won't need a transit visa).

Comment: Aside, in case you end up having to apply for a visa for some reason: Schengen visas do not come in separate types for business and pleasure.  Rather, you have to provide justification for the purpose of your trip, which may be a business purpose or not.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why can't the traveler pass through, say, Germany on the way?  Germany apparently also [allows visa-free travel for refugees](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/03__Consulates/Los__Angeles/03/Visa__Procedure.html).  Victor should therefore be fine booking a flight on Lufthansa.

Comment: @phoog Yes, he probably could. The point is that he'll need to check his transit points carefully. Especially if his company is buying the plane tickets.

Comment: @MichaelHampton agreed.  Travelers using a refugee document has to consider each Schengen country's visa requirements separately.  (The same is true for visa nationals who are traveling on diplomatic or service passports.)

Comment: I'm just not sure why this is mark as a duplicate when i have a specific questions. Anyway, i called the General Consulate of Belgium in NY. Explained about my immigration status and the purpose of my visit there. The rep said i dont need visa. Although, she clarified that it's a short term visit and will not be paid in Euro.